# VBA IE Form Automation

Tags: vba, webforms

Many posts along the same lines I know however am really struggling to get this working.

I've created code which logs into a website, clicks on a button which opens a new tab with forms, however I am unable to enter data into the forms despite trying various examples from other posts.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
''=======================================================
'' Program:   MyQuote
'' Desc:      Writes Data into online web form from data in workbook
'' Called by: Batch File (MyQuote.bat)
'' Call:      MyQuote
'' Info:
    ''This macro has been built improve the time it takes to gain a quotation from the MyQuote website.
    ''Once an agent has completed a quote on the inhouse system, they will run batch file (MyQuote.bat) which FTP's out the quote data, imports it into this
    ''workbook, and uses that data to fill the quote forms on the MyQuote website.
    ''The macro creates a new instance of Internet Explorer, navigates to the site, enters the username and password to login, and navigates through
    ''each question entering the variable extracted from our quote system.
'' Changes----------------------------------------------
'' Date         Programmer       Change
'' 13/01/2017   Craig               Written
''=======================================================
Sub MyQuote()

'Declaring the necessary variables.
    Dim IE              As Object


Dim Bton1 As HTMLGenericElement


'Set browser
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Log Off if already logged in
        IE.navigate "http://www.example.com/logout"

'Wait until IE has loaded
        Do Until IE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop


'Navigate to My Quote Website
        IE.navigate "http://www.example.com/"

'Wait until IE has loaded
        Do Until IE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop


'Enter values and login to My Quote Website
        IE.document.all.Item("UserName").Value = "user@example.co.uk"
        IE.document.all.Item("Password").Value = "abc"


'Find and press the submit button
        Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")


        If objCollection(i).Type = "submit" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        End If


        objElement.Click


'Wait while IE re-loads...
        While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend

'Find and press the New Quote button
        Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")

        If objCollection(i).className = "btn btn-success btn-xs" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
        End If


        objElement.Click


'Wait while IE re-loads...
        While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend


'Find and press the Agree button on Credit Check pop up overlay
        For Each l In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
            If l.className = "btn btn-success" Then l.Click
            Next

'Wait while IE re-loads...
        While IE.Busy
            DoEvents
        Wend

'Enter Registration
        '=====below is what is not working======
        'IE is now in a new tab with different URL if that helps
        IE.document.all.Item("Registration").Value = "AB12CDE"

        End With




End Sub
```

I am unable to supply the actual URL/passwords etc.. of the site, however below is a snippet of the HTML of the page and element I am trying to get working:

```
                        <input type="text" name="Registration" id="Registration" class="form-control reg-input" data-bind="value: Registration" placeholder="REGISTRATION">
                        <button id="btn-findVehicle" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.findVehicle">Find your car </button>
```

I don't know if this is because I am trying to select an object and I am now in a new IE tab, but I've spent 10 hours trying to get this working without any luck.

Once this is fixed I can move on with mapping the other 40 fields, radio buttons, drop down menu's & submit buttons (wish me luck).

Any help and advice appreciated.

Regards

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using getElementById method, because your id is really eassy to find and looking to be static, you can check the method in the MSDN.

I have automated a lot of browser work with the help of a free third party software - you can check it - OPEN TWEBST. 
I only had problems with it navigating web pages, which required e-signature.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alen, I have used to ID element also. It was actually due to the browser navigating to another tab which was causing the issue. I just navigated to the page it was opening in the current tab and all is working.
Thanks